# What characters do LTRIM and RTRIM trim exactly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`LTRIM` and `RTRIM` [are documented to trim "blanks"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx). What characters are considered "blank" exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. Although there are many [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) characters defined in Unicode, only a space (0x0020) is removed:

```
with Characters as (
  select NChar( 0 ) as Character
  union all
  select NChar( Unicode( Character ) + 1 )
    from Characters
    where Unicode( Character ) < 65535 ),
  CharacterMap as (
  select Unicode( Character ) as [UnicodePoint], Character,
    1 - Len( LTrim( Character ) ) as [Whitespace]
    from Characters )
  select UnicodePoint, Character, Whitespace
    from CharacterMap
    where Whitespace = 1
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

(The same applies to `RTrim`.)