# Removing trailing spaces and whitespaces from SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, record, trim

I have a column in my SQL Server database and it has white spaces from left and right site of the record. Basically it's a `nvarchar(250)` column.

I have tried removing white spaces completely like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET whitespacecolumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(whitespacecolumn))
```

But this didn't work out at all, the whitespace is still there. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What characters are the white space? Trim only removes spaces. Not tabs or other types of white space.

Comment: Im not sure which kind of charachters they are, but theres an empty space in front of the records like this: (this space here) username

Comment: @MartinSmith How to remove the tabs/enter ?

Comment: You need to know by what number they are represented in particular encoding. For example in UTF-8, 13 number is for space, then you can replace it with `REPLACE(col, char(13), '')`. Since I am not sure about encoding (most surely it's UTF-8), I would suggest trying yourself.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn this goes with update statement ?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you mean by that, but this should work:
`UPDATEsomeTable set col = REPLACE(col, ... , ...)`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35247507/92546) answer may help with removing whitespace characters in general. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35245374/92546) answer shows the characters that `LTrim` and `RTrim` remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below;

1. Find any special characters like char(10), char(13) etc in the field value.
2. Check the status of ANSI_PADDING ON. Refer this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql) article.

Answer (score 1):

I think replace is the way as you are looking to update

```
UPDATE MyTable SET whitespacecolumn = Replace(whitespacecolumn, ' ', '')
```

you can try doing select first and then prefer to update

```
SELECT *, Replace(whitespacecolumn, ' ', '') from MyTable
```

LTRIM, RTRIM will remove spaces in front and rear of column. In 2016 you can use TRIM function as below to trim special characters as well:

```
SELECT TRIM( '.,! ' FROM  '#     test    .') AS Result;
```

Output:

```
# test
```

Comment: Support for the `TRIM()` function is available in SQL Server 2017; as far as I can tell, it is *not* available in SQL Server 2016 or below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql